# How can I loop PyAutoGUI's locateCenterOnScreen until the image is found?

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm running Python 3.8.10 on Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.

How can I modify:

```
a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/home/image01.png', confidence=0.6, region=(25,500,1700,570))
```

so that it loops until `image01.png` is found?

See, in my script, the following works approximately 90% of the time for me:

```
a, b = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('/home/image01.png', confidence=0.6, region=(25,500,1700,570))
```

But about 10% of the time it fails resulting in:

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Based on [Why can't pyautogui locate my image although the code seems to be just fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68140109/why-cant-pyautogui-locate-my-image-although-the-code-seems-to-be-just-fine) it seems like instead of running my code once, perhaps I should loop the following function until the image is detected.

I don't know how to implement it, but once again based on [Why can't pyautogui locate my image although the code seems to be just fine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68140109/why-cant-pyautogui-locate-my-image-although-the-code-seems-to-be-just-fine)
the following seems like it would be helpful...

```
def detect_image(path, duration=0):
    while True:
        image_location = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(path)
        if image_location:
            pyautogui.click(image_location[0], image_location[1], duration=duration)
            break
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to do something similar not long ago.

First of all I imported 'Pyautogui' as 'pe' and also I imported time.

So this is what I did.

```
waitingloop = 1
```

I defined a waiting loop that is equal to one, and then using that I wrote

```
    while waitingloop == 1:
        if pe.locateCenterOnScreen('signinbox.png') == None:
            time.sleep(0.5)
        else:
            time.sleep(0.5)
            pe.typewrite(email)
            pe.hotkey('enter')
            break
```

So as you can see, with the 'waitingloop' this process will be running all the time, and then *everytime IT FAILS* to locate the image and returns 'None' it sleeps for 0.5 seconds and tries to do so again *until it actually finds the image*, then when it finds it as you can see it just does what I wanted it to do **(in your case it would be 'click')** and once it does that the loop breaks.

I hope this code can help you.

Comment: I haven't tested it yet, but that looks like an elegant solution which I guess is correct because the logic seems to be clear and concise! Which country do you live in? Are you interested in doing any freelance work?

Comment: Thanks! I'm from Dominican Republic. I've heard a bit about freelance work but I don't really know how it works, it would be interesting though. I'm still a student though so I don't really know how that would work.

Comment: Please email me at...

winston1420 AT yek.anonaddy.com

That's a disposable email address.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is about a year old, but the other answer is no longer relevant since locateCenterOnScreen() does not return None anymore, so this answer is for anyone who looked this up.

At the start of the program you must have this function.

```
pyautogui.useImageNotFoundException()
```

This code loops infinitely with a try-catch until locateCenterOnScreen no longer raises ImageNotFoundException.

```
while True:
    try:
        x, y = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen()
        break
    except pyautogui.ImageNotFoundException:
        pass
```